# Is there a recursive version of BeanUtils.populate?

Tags: java, apache-commons

org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils:

```
BeanUtils.populate(Object bean, Map<String,? extends Object> properties);
Populate the JavaBeans properties of the specified bean, based on the specified name/value pairs.
```

Is there a recursive version of BeanUtils.populate?

```
class Person {
  String name;
  Address address;
}
class Address {
  String street;
  int number
}
```

so that calling populate on Person, it would also populate address (assuming Address has a default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using dot(.). Say if you want to set the street inside address object specify the property name like `address.street` eg

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
propertyMap.put("name", "James Bond");
propertyMap.put("address.street", "London");
propertyMap.put("address.number", "007");

BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().populate(bean, propertyMap);
```

Comment: this only works if bean.address != null. that is, BeanUtilsBean.populate() does not instantiate Address.

Comment: what about a List<Address>?

Comment: @arisalexis For Collections fields, propertyMap.put("addressList[0].number", "007");